# JavaME in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, java-me, eclipse-plugin

I use Eclipse Ganymede IDE. In this IDE How to run a JavaME Application? What are the tools are needed to run a sample application ? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [EclipseME](http://eclipseme.org/) plugin to develop a small application some time ago. It seems it has become an official Eclipse project.

Answer (score -2):

You can create a java project and run with KEmulator.

Comment: It's a wanderful JavaME Emulator.Check this out:http://cn.bing.com/search?setmkt=zh-CN&q=kemulator

Comment: your link is in the language I don't understand. Can you summarize it in English?

Comment: U can use google translate.And it's just a usefull JavaME Emulator.U can download it from [here](http://www.sisdown.com/UploadFiles/PC/KEmulator_SISDOWN.rar).
And check here for the [manual](http://lyo.blogsome.com/kemulator/manual/)